# Как поместить info-кпопку(или другую) на программно созданный navigatorBar?

Tags: xcode

Я создал программно кнопку

```
//описание для левой кнопки
UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"info" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(info)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
```

выглядит она не очень как мне хотелось, как заменить эту квадратную на кнопку-info(кружочек) как на картинке?

ссылка на картинку
http://shot.qip.ru/00nLCH-59Wc49oMe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создать info-кнопку

`UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];`

1. Добавить на нее нужный target-action

`[button addTarget:self action:@selector(info) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

1. Инициализировать ею UIBarButtonItem

`UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];`
`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;`

Comment: а можно как нибудь подвинуть иконку немного вправо? на 0.5 см? нужно использовать fixed space bar я так понимаю ?

Answer (score 0):

Стандартные элементы `UIToolBar` и `UINavigationBar` создаются так

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemStop
                         target:self
                         action:@selector(handleAction)];
```

Стандартные иконки можно посмотреть [здесь](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIBarButtonItemStyle)

Если нужной иконки нет, то так

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myIcon"]
                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                         target:self
                         action:@selector(handleAction)];
```

Comment: а какие стандарты если используешь свою иконку? 16х16(32х32 ретина)?